How to read data from a binary file to a vector in c++?
I want to read a binary file into a vector. Everything seems to work fine, since all the values have the correct values.
Except the binary values/data isn't inputted into data or rather data isn`t getting populated.
void loadDataFromFile(const std::string& filePath, std::vector<DataArray>& data) 
{
    std::ifstream inFile(filePath, std::ios::binary);
    if (!inFile) {
        std::cerr << "Error opening file!" << std::endl;
    }
    
    // Get the size of the file
    inFile.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    std::streamsize file_size = inFile.tellg();
    inFile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    constexpr std::size_t bufferSize = 700 * 1024 * 1024; // 700 MB buffer size (adjust as needed)

    std::size_t elementSize = sizeof(DataArray);
    std::size_t elementsPerBuffer = bufferSize / elementSize;
    std::size_t totalElements = file_size / elementSize;

    data.reserve(totalElements);
    
    std::size_t offset = 0;
    while (offset < totalElements) {
        std::size_t count = std::min(elementsPerBuffer, totalElements - offset);

        inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&data[offset]), count * elementSize);

        offset += count;
    }

    inFile.close();
}


You want data.resize, rather than data.reserve

As above, you need to resize your vector. Must be a dupe for this

@Schtraded Not obvious why you are using a loop, why not read all the data into the vector in one go?

@john ye i did at first, which worked for smaller data, but my new complete data set is 2.361.554.352 bytes large which is above the signed int limit of the second argument which takes a std::streamsize

On my platform, std::streamsize can be as large as 9223372036854775807, which is more than enough to hold 2361554352.  The std::streamsize is the signed counterpart to std::size_t.  Akin to the POSIX ssize_t.

be aware that for non trivial enough types the operation may be undefined behavior. Typically the bytes in the file does not correspond to the object representation of the type (for instance, data written with a program from one compiler, read by a program from another one)

@Schtraded -- Are you running a 32-bit application?  If so, you may consider changing to 64-bit, as mentioned by #Eljay, the std::streamsize should be large enough for 64-bit.

It will only work for trivially copyable, trivially constructible types. Just filling the vector's memory with binary data will not start the lifetime of the objects. In general : if you want binary serialization... use a library

The issue does not actually relate to reading the data from the file, but rather to the way you attempted to set the size of the vector before populating it.
In this line:
data.reserve(totalElements);

You call std::vector::reserve which will:

Increase the capacity of the vector (the total number of elements that
the vector can hold without requiring reallocation) to a value that's
greater or equal to new_cap.

The actual size() of the vector does not change and accessing elements with index >= the current size will invoke undefined-behavior.
Instead, since you want to populate the vector with totalElements elements, you should call std::vector::resize:
data.resize(totalElements);

This will change the size() of the vector and will be able to populate the totalElements elements.
Note:
Creating objects (the elements in your vector - of type DataArray) by copying raw bytes like you do will work only for trivially copyable / trivially constructible types. If your DataArray isn't such a type you will need to do some serializations - preferably using an existing library.
